# Post-edit by 3rd party editor created errors, and 3 out of 4 editors approved

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

In my inbox, I got a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13570520) for an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584621/running-ionic-on-android-always-returns-404-error/33603937#33603937) I gave. I've restored the original content, but it's apparent that the editor is [relatively new](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123877/ali-seyedi?tab=topactivity).

My question and concern is that I have no way to inform this editor and those that approved that they created errors in my post. I can see there is a reason not to contact them directly. Is there an arbiter I can turn to?

Comment: You can @ping any editors who have successfully edited a post. Reviewers, not so much, that would require a flag.

Comment: However, mind to remove `Best of Luck, I'm to get some sleep right now. So, it will be a while before I'm back to check on this.`, it is totally not constructive IMHO.

Comment: I fixed that answer for you: Trademark capitalization; layout; grammar; removing noise.

Comment: I believe you can mention any user who had anything (within reason) to do with a post using the `@` syntax - see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284827) for a list of people who can be notified in such a way.

Answer (score 7):

The edit replaced *"you"* with *"You"*, *"that"* with *"than"*, *"one more"* with *"another"* and finally it removed *"Best of Luck, I'm to get some sleep right now. So, it will be a while before I'm back to check on this."*

The edit introduces two little grammar mistakes, and removes the final part which I think that can be considered a kind of salutation not relevant to the answer.
(Consider this question: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)).

I agree with a salutation or greetings on a posts I think that it's polite and doesn't introduce noise but this is *only my opinion*, however by the community is considered good to remove this when you're making an edit; hence are correct to remove the last part of your answer.

I would reject the edit as *not improvement whatsoever* but I don't think that the edit was so wrong to need to contact to the editor and those that approved.

Comment: Imo, "Reject/approve _and edit_" would've been the proper vote. The text at the bottom should be removed, but the other edits weren't right

Comment: Also, those greetings, salutations and other lines like that are ___noise___, and should be removed on sight.

Comment: @Cerbrus right :), probably the most appropriate action was *"Improve edit"*. But for me the point is that the edit is not so bad to need to contact with the editor.

Comment: @Cerbrus By the way thanks for the edit as you can see I don't have a very good English... :P

Comment: I consider it ***impolite*** to waste my time with noise like *"Hope that helps"*, even when there is consensus that we don't add noise like that. Of course, you hope that your post helps. Would you post if you didn't? If you want to be polite, accept the guidelines of the site.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see your point, I'll stop to add greetings in my answer (I agree or not) since it's in the guidelines :). Anyway I can't see how a greetings at the end of the post can waste your time (at least I hope not so much)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I agree that noise should be removed, but a rant against "hope that helps" is undue. All people on this site are exactly that: *people*. It is normal social conduct to add such things. Remove it as you must, it'll reduce answers to their bare content, but don't call people impolite and "wasting your time" who have put it in their answer. The "consensus" is relative, and more of a compromise between different views than a 100% "agreed" by everyone anyway. And any consensus is subject to change too...